# $TM$ and $T^*M$ are isomorphic vector bundles

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

> Let $M^m$ be a smooth manifold. Prove that $\pi:TM\to M$ and $\pi^*:T^*M\to M$ are isomorphic vector bundles using the fact that every manifold admits a riemannian metric.

Here is what I've thought about:

Take $(U_p, X)$ a chart in $p\in U_p\subset M$, then $\left\{\left.\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1} \right|_{u}, \dots, \left.\frac{\partial }{\partial x_m} \right|_{u}\right\}$ is a basis for $T_uM$ and $\{\text{d}x_{1_{u}}, \dots, \text{d}x_{m_{u}}\}$ is a basis for $(T_uM)^*$ for every $u\in U_p$. Define $\phi_p:TU_p \to T^*U_p$ as:

$$\phi_p\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_i\left.\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i} \right|_{u}\right):=\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_i\text{d}x_{i_{u}}.$$

That should give us a local isomorphism. Using a partition of unity, we can define a global isomorphism map $\phi:TM \to T^*M$.

First question: is this correct? Second: how could I possibly use a riemannian metric in this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any two rank $k$ vector bundles on $X$ are locally isomorphic as they are locally trivial, but these local isomorphisms do not patch together to give a global isomorphism in general.

Instead, let $g$ be a Riemannian metric. Then consider the vector bundle morphism $\Phi : TM \to T^*M$ given by $v \mapsto g(v, \cdot)$. By the non-degeneracy of $g$, you should be able to show that $\Phi$ is injective, then using the fact that $TM$ and $T^*M$ have the same rank, you can conclude $\Phi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Just to explicitly  answer the first question in the OP's question: no, your proof is not correct (exactly because, as Michael said in the first part of his answer, you only get a local isomorphism in the way you work, and this doesn't necessarily induce a global one).

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud I see what you mean, thanks! My only question now is: how to prove that $v\mapsto g(v, \dot{} )$ is smooth?

Comment: @AguirreK **Hint:** Use the fact that $g$ is smooth. If you really want, you can choose local trivializations of the bundles and work in coordinates.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Is the following argumentation correct? "Let $X, Y\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, then $p\mapsto \Phi(X_p)(Y_p)=g_p(X_p, Y_p)$ is smooth, since $g$ is a riemannian metric. Therefore, $\Phi$ is smooth." I suppose that's probably what I should do with your hint, but I'm not sure about the conclusion "therefore $\Phi$ is smooth".